# Read textfiles outside tomcat/bin

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a java web application that I'm running with tomcat. This application has to read from a couple of text files, and currently I have them sitting in tomcat's bin, since that is the working directory.

How would I get tomcat to look elsewhere for the textfiles, without relying on absolute paths? ideally, I'd like to put the files in WEB-INF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the files in WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib, then they'll be on the classpath and you can read them using

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("Yourfilename.abc");
```